# In fortran 90 how to give a summation upper limit upto infinity??? I am using NETBEANS 8.01

Tags: netbeans

I have tried the following code:

```
program practice
    implicit none
    real :: a,b,c,d,E
    b = 10
    a = 20
    c = a*b
    do d = 1, -alog(0), 1
        E = c**d
    print*, "The value of E is: ", E
    end do
end program practice
```

This is not working beacuse -alog(0) is not recognized as limit. It is showing error.